# Removing carriage return and linefeed from the end of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

How do I remove the carriage return character `(\r)` and
the Unix newline character`(\n)` from the end of a string?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

This will trim off any combination of carriage returns and newlines from the end of `s`:

```
s = s.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
```

**Edit**: Or as JP kindly points out, you can spell that more succinctly as:

```
s = s.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```

Comment: Take note of the params keyword in the declaration of TrimEnd, it let's you pass multiple instances of a character instead of the array.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(VS.71).aspx

Comment: How about this: s = s.TrimEnd(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

Comment: I've been writing c# since v1.0 came out (10 years ago). Now you tell me about TrimEnd. Doh!

Comment: Just out of interest, all you really need is `s = s.TrimEnd()` - as the docs say:  _If trimChars is null or an empty array, Unicode white-space characters are removed instead._ - see [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)

Comment: @StuartWood: ...which is not what Avik asked for.  He asked specifically for `'\r'` and `'\n'` and nothing else, not the space character `' '` for instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973524/how-to-remove-extra-returns-and-spaces-in-a-string-by-regex/4974031#4974031

Comment: Here is the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35890472/229930

Answer (score 34):

This should work ...

```
var tst = "12345\n\n\r\n\r\r";
var res = tst.TrimEnd( '\r', '\n' );
```

Answer (score 22):

```
String temp = s.Replace("\r\n","").Trim();
```

`s` being the original string.  (Note capitals)

Comment: That will also: 1) Remove \r\n from the middle of the string, 2) Remove any whitespace characters from the start of the string, and 3) remove any whitespace characters from the end of the string.

Comment: True, I assumed only one /r/n at the end. It wasn't mentioned in the orginal post. I'm not sure that warrents a -1 vote

Comment: Is using `replace()` then `trim()` not overkill when `TrimEnd()` can do the job alone, or am I missing something?

Comment: great suggestion @MattBaker

Comment: It's better separate in this mode, `s.Replace("\n","").Replace("\r","").trim()`

Answer (score 20):

If you are using multiple platforms you are safer using this method.

```
value.TrimEnd(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

It will account for different newline and carriage-return characters.

Comment: JP's method -- `tst.TrimEnd( '\r', '\n' )` -- is reasonably "safe" in practice since major EOLs are [currently] just different combos of `\r` and `\n`, but alexw's is the "right" answer. *Let the CLR tell you what chars are in this platform's newline.* [EOL hasn't always been combos of 0Ds and 0As](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations)

Comment: I used to use `Environment.NewLine` but it didn't seem to handle instances where `\r` was present without `\n`.  `TrimEnd('r','\n')` seems to be more reliable in this case.

Comment: It could be that this is actually a cross-platform issue, and dec needs to specifically remove both \r \n, irrespective of what the system environment says.

Answer (score 10):

```
s.TrimEnd();
```

The above is all I needed to remove '\r\n' from the end of my string.

The upvoted answer seems wrong to me.  Firstly, it didn't work when I tried, secondly, if it did work I would expect that s.TrimEnd('\r', '\n') would only remove *either* a '\r' or a '\n', so I'd have to run it over my string twice - once for when '\n' was at the end and the second time for when '\r' was at the end (now that the '\n' was removed).

Comment: This does work to remove \r and \n but will also remove all white space, so in some cases may go too far.  Note the doc for this method: " If trimChars is null or an empty array, Unicode white-space characters are removed instead."

Answer (score 4):

If there's always a single CRLF, then:

```
myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 2);
```

If it may or may not have it, then:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\r\n$");
re.Replace(myString, "");
```

Both of these (by design), will remove at most a single CRLF.  Cache the regex for performance.

Answer (score 4):

For us VBers:

```
TrimEnd(New Char() {ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.Lf})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string k = "This is my\r\nugly string. I want\r\nto change this. Please \r\n help!";
k = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(k, @"\r\n+", " ");
```

Answer (score 3):

This was too easy -- for me I'm filtering out certain email items.  I'm writing my own custom email junk filter.  With \r and/or \n in the string it was wiping out all items instead of filtering.

So, I just did filter = filter.Remove('\n') and filter = filter.Remove('\r').  I'm making my filter such that an end user can use Notepad to directly edit the file so there's no telling where these characters might embed themselves -- could be other than at the start or end of the string.  So removing them all does it.

The other entries all work but Remove might be the easiest?

I learned quite a bit more about Regex from this post -- pretty cool work with its use here.

Comment: Looks like you could do just `filter = filter.Remove('\n').Remove('\r');`

Answer (score 2):

I use lots of erasing level

```
String donen = "lots of stupid whitespaces and new lines and others..."

//Remove multilines
donen = Regex.Replace(donen, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
//remove multi whitespaces
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
donen = regex.Replace(donen, " ");
//remove tabs
char tab = '\u0009';
donen = donen.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");
//remove endoffile newlines
donen = donen.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
//to be sure erase new lines again from another perspective
donen.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

and now we have a clean one row

Answer (score 2):

This is what I got to work for me.

```
s.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
varName.replace(/[\r\n]/mg, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the nuget [IvanStoychev.Useful.String.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IvanStoychev.Useful.String.Extensions/) you can do:

`s = s.TrimEnd(Environment.Newline);`

It adds an overload of `TrimEnd` that takes a `string`.