# How to remove extra returns and spaces in a string by regex?

Tags: c#, regex, return, space

I convert a HTML code to plain text.But there are many extra returns and spaces.How to remove them?

Comment: it sounds obvious, but if replacing spaces and CRLFs doesn't beautify your HTML enough, you may consider using an [HTML formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120971/382515)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to

- find two or more consecutive spaces and replace them with a single space, and
- find two or more consecutive newlines and replace them with a single newline.

If that's correct, then you could use

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1");
```

This keeps the original "type" of whitespace intact and also preserves Windows line endings correctly. If you also want to "condense" multiple tabs into one, use

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"( |\t|\r?\n)\1+", "$1");
```

To condense a string of newlines and spaces (any number of each) into a single newline, use

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?:(?:\r?\n)+ +){2,}", @"\n");
```

Comment: +1 for maintaining new lines and only collapsing duplicates of the same type

Comment: good,but there is on more suitation cannot solve.like `\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n` returns mixed with spaces

Comment: And what do you want the result to be in that case? What if you have something like `\n\n \n\n \n\n` or `\n  \n  \n  \n` or `\n  \n\n \n  \n\n \n  \n\n` etc.?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I want sequent spaces to " " sequent returns to "\n",and then returns with spaces like `\n\n \n\n \n\n   \n` to "\n".ps:there are more  than one space between "\n"s

Comment: I think I can do it by replacing the string twice.First jsut like the answer.Next,replace `\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n`.

Comment: I have added another regex for this case; this would have to be applied before or after the other regex.

Comment: (.NET) If you want to keep the carriage returns which are  included with \s, use [ \t] instead of \s.   
    //remove multiple carriage returns
    txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1");
    // remove duplicate blank spaces or multiple tabs
    <!-- language: c# -->
    txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"[ \t]+", " ");
    // remove blank lines or lines consisting of spaces and tabs
    txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"^[ \t]+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();

Comment: @TimPietzcker What would be the change in this regex, `Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1");`  If I want to remove the `\r\n` as well

Comment: @AmmarKhan: Would you also want to remove spaces? If yes, just replace the match with an empty string. If not, it's complicated, and an answer wouldn't fit inside a comment.

Answer (score 18):

[`string new_string = Regex.Replace(orig_string, @"\s", "")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) will remove all whitespace

`string new_string = Regex.Replace(orig_string, @"\s+", " ")` will just collapse multiple whitespaces into one

Comment: Thank you,what about returns?

Comment: I really loved the way you removed the spaces ;-)

Comment: `\s` is a shorthand for space, newline, tab and form feed (and some other whitespace in some implementations), so it will remove those returns and convert them into a single space.

Answer (score 0):

I used a lot of algorithm for that. Every loop was good but this was clear and absolute.

```
//define what you want to remove as char

char tb = (char)9; //Tab char ascii code
spc = (char)32;    //space char ascii code
nwln = (char)10;   //New line char ascii char

yourstring.Replace(tb,"");
yourstring.Replace(spc,"");
yourstring.Replace(nwln,"");

//by defining chars, result was better.
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Trim() to remove the spaces and returns. In HTML the spaces is not important so you can omit them by using the Trim() method in System.String class.

Comment: I think trim can just remove start space and end space

Comment: In fact, only leading and trailing characters are supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx. +1 for suggesting an alternative though, maybe try to expand idea on this for the OP and give a regexless solution?

Comment: You can remove white spaces and also other chars you may want to remove. If you want to remove returns, I think the best way is Use this: "Your Html".Trim('\n')

Comment: The point is, it only removes them from the **beginning** and **end** of the string.  The OP is trying to collapse whitespace throughout the string.  `Trim` may be useful, but it won't do the whole job.