# How to match multiple newline in xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, regex

Need help on matching multiple newline in xml file using Regular expression

I want to delete the multiple newline in an xml file content below

```
<pg>Data</pg>
<url>Data</url>
<pdate>Data</pdate>
<pdy>Data</pdy>
<pdm>Data</pdm>



<pdd>Data</pdd>
<dat>Data</dat>
<tom>Data</tom>
<des>Data</des>
<abs>Data</abs>
<geo>Data</geo>
<org>Data</org>
<per>Data</per>
```

Need help please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973524/how-to-remove-extra-returns-and-spaces-in-a-string-by-regex

Comment: it is not working on regexpal.com sir

Comment: Works for me on regexhero!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `PreserveWhitespace` Property  Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If PreserveWhitespace is true before Save is called, white space in the document is preserved in the output; otherwise, if this property is false, XmlDocument auto-indents the output.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
```