# getting text-nodes of HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, browser, dom

After WebBrowser document loads, Its document contains something like:

```
<div id="toextract">
    <div>This</div>
    <div>is</div>
    Sample
    <div>text</div>
    I
    <div>want to</div>
    <div>Extract</div>
</div>
```

I want to extract InnerHtml of these elements so that the output would be:

**This is Sample text I want to Extract**

but i get this:

**This is text want to Extract**

as the word **I** and **Sample** are not in an HtmlElement. this is my code:

```
string Ex = "";
HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("toextract");
HtmlElementCollection elems = elem.All
for(int i=0;i<elems.Count;i++)
    Ex += elems[i].InnerHtml + " ";
```

my code skips text-nodes (nodes with no tag). I think its because they are not considered as HtmlElement. 
How can include them in my extracted text?

Comment: you assume right, the html is not entirely valid. Do you expect other violations other than missing tags? (like non closing tags <div>text<div>other text</div> ?

Comment: No, the only problem is these text nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply fetch the text with

> elem.InnerText

and remove any linefeeds like this

> elem.InnerText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ")

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from elements to childNodes and then stripping away the unneeded whitespaces and line breaks. Something like this (not yet tested):

```
string Ex = "";
HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("toextract");
NodeList nodes = elem.childNodes;
for(int i=0;i<nodes.Count;i++)
    Ex += nodes[i].data + " ";
Ex = Regex.Replace(Ex, @"(?:(?:\r?\n)+ +){2,}", @" ");
```

For similar Q&A, see
[best way to get child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)
and
[How to remove extra returns and spaces in a string by regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973524/how-to-remove-extra-returns-and-spaces-in-a-string-by-regex)